# Does the rotational form of Newton's second law always hold?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, rigid-body-dynamics

Does the equation,
$$\vec \tau=I\vec \alpha$$
(rotational form of the second law) always hold? If not, in what conditions does it hold true?

Answer (score 2):

> Does the equation,$$\vec \tau = \mathrm I \vec\alpha$$(rotational form of the second law) always hold?

No. This assumes a rigid body, that the body is rotating about one of the principal axes of the rigid body, and that the external torque is parallel (or anti-parallel) to the body's rotation axis.

Comment: So if the external torque is not parallel (or anti-parallel) to the body's rotation axis the equation would not hold true  ? :0

Comment: The simplified version always holds for spherical bodies because every axis of a spherical body is a principal axis. For a non-spherical body that isn't rotating about a principal axis, the simplified form doesn't even hold in the case of zero torque. For a non-spherical body that happens to be rotating about a principal axis, a net torque that isn't parallel/anti-parallel will make the body rotate about a non-principal axis, and then the simplified form doesn't hold, either. Finally, for a non-rigid body, the simplified form doesn't hold, period.